# Why these 'undefined' warnings when I compile the driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver, spi

I cross compiled [this code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c?v=3.4) for pandaboard, I get the following warnings.

I've included the header file `#include <linux/spi/spi.h>` which has the prototypes of below the functions.

The definitions of the below functions are in [spi.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi.c?v=3.4#L837)

```
WARNING: "spi_register_master" [..../spi-omap2-mcspi.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "spi_alloc_master" [..../spi-omap2-mcspi.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "spi_unregister_master" [..../spi-omap2-mcspi.ko] undefined!
```

In what way I can link these function definitions to my module [spi-omap2-mcspi.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c?v=3.4)

Comment: If you are compiling spi-omap2-mcspi.c as external module then check CONFIG_SPI_MASTER enabled or not in the KSRC path

Comment: It's not enabled anywhere in the KSRC path. Where shall I enable it ?

Comment: did u verified .config? or on your board vim /proc/config.gz?. If it not enabled in the kernel your are running then you need to do make menuconfig and enable it.

For simplest solution give a try to compile spi.c along with spi-omap2-mcspi.c.

Comment: config.gz file is not present in the board.

Comment: Ok If it is not possible to update KSRC with updated config then  try to compile spi.c along with spi-omap2-mcspi.c.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to enable `CONFIG_SPI_OMAP24XX`.

To do this, simply run `make menuconfig` or just open `.config` and find `CONFIG_SPI_OMAP24XX=[ymn]` then set it 'y'.
In case of you edit .config directly, you need to run `make oldconfig`.

Update spi-omap2-mcspi.c and run `make modules` would compile that module.